# How to execute pig script and save the result in another file?

Tags: apache-pig

I have a "solution.pig" file which contain all load, join and dump queries. I need to run them by typing "solution.pig" in grunt> and save all the result in other file. How can I do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the file directly with `pig -f solution.pig`. Don't open the grunt REPL

And in the file, you can use as many [`STORE` commands](https://pig.apache.org/docs/latest/func.html#load-store-functions) as you want to save results into files, rather than `DUMP`